# Eclipse app for android though, rookie

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm starting to learn how to develop apps for android. This is my first project (tests) and it keep giving me the same error... " The application has stopped unexpectedly" and I can't figure out where is the problem.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.layoutxml2;

>import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

            final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Button carregar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            carregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    text1.setText("Xau Pessoal!");

                }
            });


        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.layoutxml2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:background="#285178" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/banner"
        android:src="@drawable/androidbanner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/saudacao"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/carregar"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="selfdestruct" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat

```
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.layoutxml2/com.example.layoutxml2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.example.layoutxml2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-14 16:33:35.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     ... 11 more
```

Sorry if the error is obvious but i'm really new in this stuff and i want to improve.
Thank you for the help :)
Regards,
Ricardo Moreira

Comment: Did you read the stacktrace? You have a `NullPointerException` in the `onCreate` method at line 28. Find out which line this is in your editor, then determine what is null and why. If I'd have to guess, I'd say it was this line `carregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Comment: I am not sure, because I have not use `ActionBarActivity` yet, but in the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) says that you need a `onCreateView()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the Button in the Fragment layout but use them in the activity. Move the code into the Fragment class into the onCreateView method and use rootview.findViewById()...

```
package com.example.layoutxml2;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);

            final TextView text1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Button carregar = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            carregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    text1.setText("Xau Pessoal!");

                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "Move the code into the Fragment class into the onCreateView class and use rootview.findViewById()..." is to move the code `final TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   Button carregar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   
   carregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     text1.setText("@string/xau");
     
    }
   });` into the fragment_main.xml and create a class onCreateView?

Comment: I edited my post above. Sorry for the fast answer yesterday, but I wrote it from my tablet. The reason for moving the code to the fragment is that you declared the textview and button resource within the layout for your fragment and not for your activity. When you inflate your activity layout in the Activity, the resources cannot be found as they are not declared in this layout. Thus, when you inflate your fragment layout within the fragment's onCreateView method you can get them.